# why error correction is required in datamatrix encoding?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am working on a data-matrix encoding technique,i studied ECC-200 encoding methods, in    ECC-200 method for 8x8 data-matrix they are using 8bit data,in that 8bit 3bit used for data and remaining 5bit for error correction.but i want to use full 8bit for data.So how to do this by avoiding error correction code-words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the specification, DataMatrix is 8x8 + 2 for the alignment and finder patterns. So it's usually called a 10x10. It is not possible to change number of bits available for data vs error correction. They are fixed and not customizable like QRCode can do.

A 10x10 symbol size has 3 codewords of data and 5 codewords of error; which gives 62.5% of error correction. You cannot change this.

Be careful to not be confused by bits vs codewords. In a 10x10 (8x8 data region), 3 codewords of data correspond to 6 numeric value, or 3 alphanumeric, or 1 byte.

You can find more information here: http://www.barcodephp.com/en/2d/datamatrix/technical

You can see how many type of characters you can include in each size.